# Parallel Make Output

Tags: build-process, makefile, cmake

When running a CMake generated Makefile with multiple processes (`make -jN`), the output often gets messed up like this:

```
[  8%] [  8%] [  9%] Building CXX object App/CMakeFiles/App.dir/src/File1.cpp.o
Building CXX object App/CMakeFiles/App.dir/src/File2.cpp.o
Building CXX object App/CMakeFiles/App.dir/src/File3.cpp.o
```

I'm not sure, but I think this behavior is also there for Makefiles not generated by CMake. I'd say it happens when multiple processes write to stdout at the same time.

I know I'm probably being pedantic, but is there any (simple) fix to this? ;)

Comment: Yes, this is caused by multiple processes writing to the terminal at the same time; probably one `echo` per `[NN%]` and one per `Building...` message, as `echo` likely uses only one syscall to do its output, making it atomic. I've only encountered this kind of behavior with too-fancy build systems such as `CMake`. No quick fix, sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using GNU make, you can do it by redefining `SHELL` such that commands are wrapped by a trivial utility that ensures atomicity of information printed to standard output.  [Here's](http://www.cmcrossroads.com/article/descrambling-parallel-build-logs) a more detailed description, including sample source for the wrapper utility.

Comment: Doesn't that solution mean your parallel build just became as good as -j1?

Comment: Hm, is this really going to work? "Output is handled on a per-command basis, not per-target.", but that's the issue here, one target outputting two things non-atomically.

Comment: @richq: no, it does not serialize the build, only the console output.  Hopefully printing console output is a tiny, tiny part of the work your build actually does -- most of your build should be doing real work like, say, compiling and linking.

Comment: @lucas: if you need all the rules to be treated atomically, you can either use the solution I linked above AND enable the .ONESHELL feature in gmake 3.82; or you can use something like [ElectricAccelerator](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator.php), a commercial replacement for gmake that handles this and other issues with parallel builds.

Comment: @Pubby: sorry, your link actually directs to a plagiarized copy of my original article on CM Crossroads.  The link I provided is the correct source.  Please feel free to check the publication dates on the two.

Comment: @EricMelski You're correct - I only meant that the source code is correctly formatted (at least on my computer the original article's code is incorrect). Very helpful article, apologies for the plagiarism and my spreading of it.

Answer (score 5):

I tried to get the CMake people to fix this, but apparently they don't want to. See http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=7062.

Answer (score 2):

The specific CMake bug related to interleaved `make` output using `-jN` with N>1 is [CMake bug 0012991: "Parallel build output mess"](http://public.kitware.com/Bug/view.php?id=12991).  It is still open in the "backlog" state waiting to be fixed.

This bug is actually annoying enough that it's a strong reason to switch to [Ninja](http://martine.github.io/ninja/) instead of *make*. Plus the fact that *Ninja* is faster than *make*.  Ninja also uses an appropriate number of parallel jobs based on the number of CPU cores present. Also cool is how Ninja is, by default, very quiet: all progress happens on a single line in the terminal unless the build process emits messages or a build step fails.  If a build step fails, Ninja prints the full command line that invoked it and displays the output.  It's really nice since it makes any warning or error messages stand out. Although currently there is no colored terminal output: that would be a nice improvement but for me the advantages of *Ninja* over *make* are tremendous.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it is already [fixed](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Output.html). Add a `-Oline` parameter to the command line:

```
make -j 8 -Oline
```

Version of make:

```
GNU Make 4.3
Built for x86_64-pc-msys
```

Answer (score 0):

Sun's (now Oracle's) `dmake` available on Linux and Solaris takes care of that.
See [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19205-01/819-5273/aexbx/index.html) and [there](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/805-4949/6j4magsu0/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple working example of using a wrapper for Make. I'm not sure if I'd encourage it's use, but it's an idea.

```
# Makefile
SHELL = /tmp/test/wrapper

test: test1 test2

test1:
    $(eval export TARGET=$@)
    env

test2:
    $(eval export TARGET=$@)
    env
```

and this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# wrapper
bash $@ | sed -e "s/^/${TARGET} /"
```